# Write a function that returns body type of customer

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data. It contains customer names and debt. If the debt is over 250 they are considered 'heavy', from 200 to 249 'medium' and from 0-199 'light'.

Data looks like this:

```
Name  Debt
John  $160 
Alex  $210
Mike  $260
```

I would like to write a function that returns 'light' in a MsgBox if the user inputs 'John' into an InputBox. I created a class for customers.

What I have so far looks like this:

```
Function ReadDebtType(amount As Integer) As Collection

InputBox ("Enter Customer Name (must exist)")

Dim Name As String
Name = InputBox.value

Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Worksheets("Data").Range("A3").CurrentRegion


    Dim coll As New Collection
    Dim c As CustomerPurchase
    Dim DebtType As String

    Dim i As Long, amount As Integer
    For i = 4 To rg.Rows.Count

    amount = rg.Cells(i, 9)

    If amount < "$200" Then
    Set c = New CustomerPurchase
    c.CustomerName = rg.Cells(i, 1)
    c.CustomerName = rg.Cells(i, 2)
    c.CustomerName = rg.Cells(i, 3)
    c.CustomerName = rg.Cells(i, 4)
    c.CustomerName = rg.Cells(i, 5)


    If pAmount < "$200" Then DebtType = "light"
        ElseIf pAmount > "$249" Then DebtType = "heavy"
        Else: DebtType = "medium"
    End If


End Function
```

But I am very lost. Anything helps. Also does this function need to be in the customer class module or can it be in a normal module?

Comment: You could utilize a `Select Case` because you can use a range of values like `Case 200 To 249` and `Case Is >= 250`

Comment: And keep in mind that if it has a dollar sign in it, then it's a string, not a value, so something like `amount < "$200"` is not going to work. It would need to be something like `CInt(Replace(amount, "$", "")) < 200`

Comment: And you dont show how you are getting `pAmount` - is that a typo or something?

Comment: pAmount is a private variable in the customer class. I guess I wouldn't be able to call it since it is private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel? This can be done much more efficiently with a Lookup function.

```
=LOOKUP(B1,{0,200,250},{"light","medium","heavy"})
```

If you need this in a VBA user form, you can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup`

Comment: how could one implement this in VB

Comment: @riddlemethisagain I wrote that in the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA implementation using @teylyn 's response. It throws an error if the person name isn't found. It assumes your data is in column A and B.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckName()

    Dim vName As String
    Dim vSheet As Worksheet

    Dim vDebtAmount As Double
    Dim vDebtType As String

    Dim vDebtLimit As Variant
    Dim vDebtDesc As Variant

    Set vSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    vDebtLimit = Array(0, 200, 250)
    vDebtDesc = Array("Light", "Medium", "Heavy")

    vName = Application.InputBox("Enter Name", "Debt Assessment")

    vDebtAmount = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(vName, vSheet.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
    vDebtType = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(vDebtAmount, vDebtLimit, vDebtDesc)

    MsgBox vDebtType

End Sub
```